# $\frac{1}{n} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am working in the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and am considering the subset $\{\frac{1}{n}: n=1,2,3,\dots\}$ (how Rudin writes it). I want to show this is bounded. It is clear to me it is bounded, but want to get practice writing it mathematically.

Since I am in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I have rewritten this as $E = \frac{1}{n} \times \{0\}$

To show it is bounded I need to show there is a real number $M > 0$ and some $q \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $p \in E$.

Attempt:

Suppose $q = (x,y)$ then
\begin{align} d((q, (\frac{1}{n},0)) & = |(x - \frac{1}{n}) + (y - 0)| \\
\leq & |x - \frac{1}{n}| + |y - 0| \\
\leq & |x - \frac{1}{n}| + |y| \\
\end{align}

Therefore $d(q,(\frac{1}{n},0)) \geq |x - \frac{1}{n}| \leq x$ for n sufficiently large. So I can take $M = x$?

thinking about this more, I don't think this is correct since this has to hold for all points in $E$ and I'm constraining it to n being large?

After comments:

Thanks for all the help, I have managed to solve it. As most of the discussion happened in the comments I will accept the answer that is not in the comments.

Comment: *Where* does Rudin write that $\frac1n$ is an element of $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: It is not true that $|x-\frac 1 n |\leq x$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos He says "Let us consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: The set consisting of the numbers $\frac{1}{n}, n=1,2,\dots$"

Comment: Rudin wrote three textbooks, each of which having several chapters…

Comment: @learningmathematics Can you provide the book title and page number ? Considering the quality of Rudin’s books this looks strange.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Its Principles of mathematical analysis Chapter 2, page 33, example 2.21 (e)

Comment: Indeed, $\{\frac 1n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ as you have interpreted correctly. Example $(g)$ in the same list on the same page is the segment $(a,b)$ which is to be interpreted as subset of $\mathbb R^2$ appropriately. Then there is a note after the list (which you have probably missed): Let us note that (d), (e), (g) can also be regarded as subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The list of examples in 2.21, wants you to view the sets given there as two cases 1) as subset of $\mathbb R$, 2) as subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and then observe the point set topology in each of the two cases.

Comment: @Koro Thanks i did miss that note. So if I view it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ I can just say its bounded by say 2 or something like that?

Comment: and that was probably done to save space. Instead of saying "$\{1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}\times \{0\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$" and $\{\frac 1n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is subset of $\mathbb R$", why not say "consider the set of numbers $\frac 1n$ where $n=1,2,...$ and view this set as subset of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ separately.

Comment: @learningmathematics: I'd say think more about the definition on (definition 2.18 bullet point (i) )of bounded set. What it essentially means is that: $E$ is bounded if you can "enclose" $E$ in an open ball of radius $M\gt 0$ centred at $q\in X$. Then you'll get your answer :)

Comment: Doesn't (x - 1/n) + (y-0)|  need an opening absolute value,  '|'  ?

Comment: @Koro I think I have it now. I can take $q$ to be a point in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and take $M > 0$ to be a radius that is greater than the maximum distance between the points in $E$ then the ball centered on $q$ with radius $M$ will contain $E$?

Comment: Why not simply take $q$ to be $(0,0)$ and then take $M=2$? Also you may like to refer theorem 1.20 part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not let x = 1 and y =0, which is q = (1, 0)?  Then if M =1, your answer simplifies quite a bit.

Then it becomes much simpler to accept, likely without elaboration or justification that
$$| 1 - \frac1n | < 1$$

Suppose $q = (1,0)$ then
\begin{align} d((q, (\frac{1}{n},0)) & = |(1 - \frac{1}{n}) + (0 - 0)| \\
= & |1 - \frac{1}{n}|  \leq 1\\
\end{align}

Also, note in your current proposed solution, a restriction **x > 1**, would be essential to eliminate **x=-1** becoming a contradiction at
$$| x - \frac1n | < x $$

Comment: My analysis is a bit rusty, if anyone catches a mistake, feel free to propose a correction.

Comment: Let $q=(x,y)$ be any member of $\Bbb R^2$ and let $ M=|x|+1+||y|.$ Then $ d(q, (1/n,0))\le$ $ d(q, (1/n,y))+d((1/n,y),(1/n,0))=$ $|x-1/n|+|y|\le |x|+|-1/n|+|y|\le M.$

Comment: Although it looks valid to me, what's the advantage to your version.  Simplicity has value.